# ngModel con Objetos para Angular no los lee

Tags: angular, typescript

EL ngModel "`[(ngModel)]="usuario.nombre`" no me lee los Objetos de usuario y no se por que sera Porfa ayudenme

En pag.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html',
  styles: [`
    .ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(form){
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  `]
})
export class TemplateComponent {

      usuario:Object= {
      nombre :"Felipe",
      apellido :"",
      correo : "",
      
    }

  

  constructor() { }

  guardar( forma:NgForm ){

    console.log('Formulario disparado');
    console.log("ngForm",forma);
    console.log("Valor",forma.value);

    console.log("Usuario: ", this.usuario);

  }

}
```

En pag.html

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="guardar(forma)" #forma="ngForm" novalidate>

 <div class="form-group row">

            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-8">

                <input #n="ngModel" class="form-control" name="nombre" 
                 [(ngModel)]="usuario.nombre" required type="text" placeholder="Nombre" minlength="5">

              
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

Comment: te marca algún error, y en que parte defines tu objeto, dentro de el ts

Comment: Ya corregí la pregunta y le agregue todo el ts mira me sale un error en el html en el ngModel  `[(ngModel)]="usuario.nombre"` ahí me sale el error ya que me sale subrayado y me dice que nombre no existe en el objeto usuario que estaré haciendo mal? @EduardoJaramilloLicea

Comment: Si me funcio asi de esa forma Gracias. Por que toca asi crear un documento usuario ts con la interface ahi

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es generado por tu tipo, defines a tu variable `usuario` como tipo `Object`, y en tu html asignas la propiedad `nombre` de tu objeto usuario, el cual en su definición no contiene un parámetro nombre.

Tienes dos posibles Soluciones, la primera quita el tipo `Object` a tu variable usuario, con lo que el angular te lo detectara como un objeto con las propiedades que le definas al inicio.

```
public usuario = { nombre: 'Felipe', apellido: 'Cruz', correo: ''}
```

Y la segunda Opción y la que mas te recomendaría, es generar una clase o interface donde defines tus propiedades y las asignas a tu variable, y así tu variable esta tipeada y tiene sus propiedades definidas.

archivo Usuario.ts

```
export interface Usuario {
  nombre: string;
  apellido: string;
  correo: string;
}
```

Archivo Component.ts

```
public usuario: Usuario = {
    nombre: '',
    apellido: '',
    correo: ''
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]